# Подскажите с++ библиотеку для работы с разреженными матрицами

Tags: c++, математика, матрицы, поиск-библиотек

В ходе написания программы я столкнулся с необходимостью решения СЛАУ где А -- разреженная матрица. Очень хотелось бы воспользоваться готовым решением, а не разбираться в алгоритмах наподобие Метода Холецкого и их реализации.
Знает ли кто-нибудь библиотеку для с++, способную решать подобные СЛАУ (а не просто имеющую класс для хранения разреженых матриц).

Comment: http://www.simunova.com/mtl4 - сами смотрите, что там есть...